Issue Using YouTube API in an Azure Function App
Apologies if any of my terminology is off I'm relatively new to dev, I am trying to create an Azure Function that is triggered by an HTTP request that sends the video_id of a YouTube video to the function and then that function proceeds to pull the transcript of that video using the youtube_transcript_api library into a string and proceeds to use that transcript string for other purposes. I am running into an issue where when I am debugging locally and send a request to localhost with the video_id the YouTube API is able to pull the transcript without any issue however when I deploy the function into Azure I am receiving this error
Result: Failure Exception: TranscriptsDisabled: Could not retrieve a transcript for the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_uLehv5lOI! This is most likely caused by: Subtitles are disabled for this video If you are sure that the described cause is not responsible for this error and that a transcript should be retrievable, please create an issue at https://github.com/jdepoix/youtube-transcript-api/issues. Please add which version of youtube_transcript_api you are using and provide the information needed to replicate the error. Also make sure that there are no open issues which already describe your problem!
Using the link you can see that the video_id was sent in properly and I made sure of this by logging the video_id to ensure there werent any issues with the HTTP Request. I would venture to guess this is probably an issue with the YouTube API blocking traffic from cloud services, not sure if there is a way around this or if there is another service that wouldnt have this issue. Let me know if anyone else has run into this issue!
Here is what the relevant portion of my code looks like...
import azure.functions as func
import logging


app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="azure_function/{video_id}")
def azure_function(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    from openai import OpenAI
    import json
    from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
   
    
    video_id = req.route_params.get('video_id', None)
    
        
    #Input video_id and output a string transcription of audio
    def transcribe_video(video_id):
        transcript_dict = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(video_id)
        
        transcript = ""
        for line in transcript_dict:
            transcript += line['text'] + " "
        return transcript

    logging.info("... starting transcription...")
    video_transcription = transcribe_video(video_id)


I have tried logging the video_id to make sure that the is was being passed through the HTTP Request correctly and I have also tried running the function locally which does work but when I deploy into Azure and run an HTTP Request I am running into the above 500 error. I appreciate any help!

While trying your code, I encountered the same error in Azure, though it works locally. This is because the YouTube API is blocked by Azure. You need to migrate to the Google API with YouTube integration to make it work on Azure.
You need to configure Google login on your Azure Function App using App Service Authentication and use google.oauth2.service_account to connect with the application.

Using above documentation we have create an application in the Google APIs console and enabled the YouTube Data API.
We need Create an OAuth client ID and add the necessary scopes to access the Google application.

Below is Azure Function code that integrates with the YouTube API to retrieve captions for a specific video.

import os
import logging
import pprint
import azure.functions as func
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'] 
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

def get_authenticated_service():
    # Create the flow using the client secrets file and the specified scopes
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)

    credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=80)
    
    return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=credentials)

def list_video_captions(service, video_id):
 
    try:
        results = service.captions().list(part='id,snippet', videoId=video_id).execute()
        items = results.get('items', [])
        
        if not items:
            logging.info('No captions found for this video.')
            return 'No captions found for this video.'
        else:
            captions_info = []
            for item in items:
                captions_info.append(item)
            logging.info('Captions: %s', pprint.pformat(captions_info))
            return captions_info
    except HttpError as error:
        logging.error(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        return f'An error occurred: {error}'

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    video_id = req.params.get('video_id')
    if not video_id:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please pass a video_id in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
    
    service = get_authenticated_service()
   
    captions_info = list_video_captions(service, video_id)

    return func.HttpResponse(
        body=pprint.pformat(captions_info),
        mimetype="application/json",
        status_code=200
    )





Output


For more details, refer to the GitHub repository and t above documents.
